# Moving spatial data off gird cell corners

Tags: r, dataframe, random, tidyverse, spatial

I have a seemingly simple question that I can’t seem to figure out.  I have a large dataset of millions of data points.  Each data point represents a single fish with its biological information as well as when and where it was caught.  I am running some statistics on these data and have been having issues which I have finally tracked down to some data points having latitude and longitude values that fall exactly on the corners of the grid cells which I am using to bin my data.  When these fish with lats and long that fall exactly onto grid cell corners are grouped into their appropriate grid cell, they end up being duplicated 4 times (one for each cell that touches the grid cell corner their lats and long identify).

Needless to say this is bad and I need to force those animals to have lats and long that don’t put them exactly on a grid cell corner.  I realize there are probably lots of ways to correct something like this but what I really need is a simply way to identify latitudes and longitudes that have integer values, and then to modify them by a very small amount (randomly adding or subtracting) so as to shift them into a specific cell without creating a bias by shifting them all the same way.

I hope this explanation makes sense.  I have included a very simple example in order to provide a workable problem.

```
fish <- data.frame(fish=1:10, lat=c(25,25,25,25.01,25.2,25.1,25.5,25.7,25,25), 
                   long=c(140,140,140,140.23,140.01,140.44,140.2,140.05,140,140))
```

In this fish data frame there are 10 fish, each with an associated latitude and longitude.  Fish 1, 2, 3, 9, and 10 have integer lat and long values that will place them exactly on the corners of my grid cells.  I need some way of shifting just these values by something like plus are minus 0.01.

I can identify which lats or longs are integers easy enough with something like:

```
fish %>%
  near(as.integer(fish$lat))
```

But am struggling to find a way to then modify all the integer values by some small amount.

Comment: What's the code that counts the fish 4 times? It seems like the problem is that it's using closed intervals rather than open intervals. It may be better to fix that problem rather than mess with your data. What's the code that's actually causing the problem?

Comment: Much later in the processing of this data, after I have converted all my data into an sf object and created a gird system that spans the Pacific I then use: st_join() to determine which points are in which cells.  At one point I was using st_intersection() but there are problems doing it that way now.  Like I said there are likely many solutions to this but altering the data by a small decimal amount is an easy solution.  Also, the data with integer values of lat and long are not real data, they are averaged points from other countries dataset presented that way for confidentially reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question I was able to work this out this morning with some pretty basic code, see below.  All it takes is making a function that actually looks for whole numbers, where is.integer does not.

```
# Used to fix the is.integer function to actually work and not just look at syntax
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol

# Use ifelse to change only whole number values of lat and long
fish$jitter_lat <- ifelse(is.wholenumber(fish$lat), fish$lat+rnorm(fish$lat, mean=0, sd=0.01), fish$lat)

fish$jitter_long <- ifelse(is.wholenumber(fish$long), fish$long+rnorm(fish$long, mean=0, sd=0.01), fish$long)
```